# Use RSA keypair for PGP encrypt and decrypt

Tags: pgp, rsa

I use PKI smartcard. I generated public and private key on my smartcard and store keys in it.
I want use these keys for PGP encryption and decryption. However, I don't know Can I make this?

Comment: You should [edit] your question such that it indicates which PGP implementation you are using. The answer will almost certainly be different for, say, GnuPG on Debian Squeeze compared to PGP on Windows.